# how to run local web application in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

can anybody tell how to run the local webapplication using android webview

I want to run my own webpages in android using web view

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the local webapplication"?

Comment: If I've answered your question, please accept the answer. If not, please provide more detail to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
private WebView mWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutWithAWebView);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.yourWebViewIdFromTheLayout);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable JavaScript

    mWebView.loadData(yourHtmlData, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Hopefully, that at least points you in the right direction.

Also, I'd recommend reading the documentation on the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), it's pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your application on the emulator, as you normally do (and be sure to have your computer connected to internet).